# Nested Each Loops Understanding

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to understand how nested `each` loops work.

Suppose I have a blog app with an `Article` model and a `Comment` model.

Looping through all my articles...

```
- @articles.each do |article|
  = article.text
```

Looping thorugh all my comments...

```
- @comments.each do |comment|
  = comment.text
```

But, what I *really* want is to loop through all the comments of a specific article--meaning nesting the second loop inside the first.

How does one achieve that?

Comment: "How does one achieve that?" - ehm, one achieves that by _nesting_ one loop in another. Not sure I understand the question. I assume you know how HAML indentation works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code should do

```
- @articles.each do |article|
  = article.text
  #level of indentation matters.
  - article.comments.each do |comment| #this will loop through respected article's comments
    = comment.text
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- @article.comments.each do |comment|
  = comment.text
```

Note this expects you to have defined a variable @article to be equal to a specific Article object, which you would normally do in the controller.